# Angular 9 - get destination url when navigation starts

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, angular9, angular-router

I'm using *Angular 9*. I need to know which will be the destination url as soon as the navigation starts.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    this.router = router;
}

this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceOf NavigationStart),
    map(event => {
        //get somehow the destination url of this navigation just started
    })
).subscribe()
```

Is there a way to achive that only with the use of Angular **Router**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e: Event): e is NavigationStart => e instanceof NavigationStart)
).subscribe((e: NavigationStart) => {
    e.url // contains the url you will go to
});
```

Comment: Ok, it works. I thought url property of `NavigationStart` would return the current url, the one prior to the navigation. Silly me